# Run a sveltekit app from file:// with no server

Tags: svelte, same-origin-policy, svelte-3, sveltekit

I basically am wondering the same things as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61966179/run-a-svelte-app-from-file-with-no-sever) except I need it for sveltekit with `adapter-static` not just svelte with rollup. There are basically 2 issues:

1. SvelteKit doesn't allow you to use `./` in the `paths.base` config option and
2. SvelteKit comiles to js modules which don't work from `file` because of `CORS`.

Any idea how to fix those issues?

Comment: May I ask why you want to run SvelteKit without a server, as this could affect how you would fix the problem?

Comment: My client wants to be able to open it with a double click on the html file

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that `http` or a localhost server (`npm run preview`) is needed to run SveteKit apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue to track this: https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/907